# How many times a word is repeated in a string with Solidity?

Tags: solidity

I needed to know how many times a word is repeated in a text string for Solidity version 0.8.*

Somedoby has a clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function:

```
function HowManyRepeated(string memory what, string memory where) public pure returns(uint){
    uint times = 0;
    if( ContainWord( what, where ) ){
        uint whatLen = CountUTF8String(what);
        uint whereLen = CountUTF8String(where);
        
        for (uint i = 0; i < whereLen - whatLen + 1 ; i++) {
            if( ContainWord( what, Substring( where, i , i + whatLen) ) ){
                times++;
            }
        }
    }
    return times;
}
```

See the complete contract functions here:

https://github.com/HermesAteneo/solidity-repeated-word-in-string/blob/main/RepeatedWords.sol